# R - applying if conditions on time data to derive values before and after certain time point

Tags: r, datetime

In my dataframe I have a date time data field.  The format is as follows:

```
2019-05-26 06:34:35
```

That is `26th May 2019 Morning 6:34 AM`.  I want to apply conditions wherein if the time is before than 6:00 AM - apply conditions to report and if the time is greater than 8:00 am apply some other condition.

```
if (df$timestamp <= 06:00) {
then condition
} elseif (df$timestamp >= 08:00 {
then some other condition
}
```

When I use strptime i am able to extract only the time part of the date time however only as character, where I am not able to apply these logical conditions.

The following is the data format

```
structure(list(Store = c("VPM", "VPM", 
"VPM"), Date = structure(c(18042, 18042, 18042), class = "Date"), 
    UniqueImageId = c("vp3_523", "vp3_668", "vp3_523"), EntryTime = structure(c(1558835514, 
    1558834942, 1558835523), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    ExitTime = structure(c(1558838793, 1558838793, 1558839824
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Duration = c(3279, 3851, 
    4301), Age = c(35L, 35L, 35L), Gender = c("Male", "Male", 
    "Male"), EntryPoint = c("Entry2Side", "Entry2Side", "Entry2Side"
    ), ExitPoint = c("Exit2Side", "Exit2Side", "Exit2Side")), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x2f9b050>)
```

Comment: @ronakshah  was in a hurry....will change the title to a meaningful one.  thank you for pointing out

Comment: you could also compare the times in base R by doing something like `as.POSIXct(format(df$EntryTime, "%T"), format = "%T") > as.POSIXct("08:00:00", format = "%T")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help, using `lubridate` library that is imho very intuitive. I've used `EntryTime` but you can apply it to any date column:

```
library(lubridate)
# it's arleady as date, so you can do this
dats$time_if <- ifelse(hour(dats$EntryTime)<= 6,'a',
                       ifelse(hour(dats$EntryTime) >= 8,'b','c' ))
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error `Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x) : 'origin' must be supplied`...any thoughts...the data field is a POSIXct one

Comment: Could you dput(yourdata) and post the ouput editing the question?

Comment: Thank you...I have added the sample data.